# How to add phone work number in address book contact?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I can modify or create a new person in my address book, but I can't find how to add a property for the phone work number.

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW3) there is no property kABPersonPhoneWorkLabel. There is the work fax number (kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel), but not phone work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ones:

```
const CFStringRef kABWorkLabel;
const CFStringRef kABHomeLabel;
const CFStringRef kABOtherLabel;
```

They are at the bottom of the document you linked, at **Generic Property Labels**

For some reasons they are separated from the other labels.